# Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. Crashing now

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

`bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x8053ce0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...`

I'm getting this error.

Today I've discovered this error for the first time, the password dialog is shown and the alertview is showing on top, which shouldn't occur till viewWillAppear when the view is shown. This all seemed to work fine when I developed this the other day. Not sure why the thread lock has been lost and how and were to implement it?

Comment: It'll be nice if we can break right when this happen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
```

...and as far as I can see that's just what you're doing. You're calling `[alertProgress dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];`, a UIKit method, from a thread other than your main thread(s), which is not allowed.

For a *very* straight forward way to call back to the main thread if you can't use GCD, take a look at [DDFoundation](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2008/05/22/invoke_on_main_thread/).

Your code would in that case only change to do;

```
[[alertProgress dd_invokeOnMainThread] dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 
                                       animated:YES];
```

Comment: But the viewcontroller and the alertview and the thread shouldn't be running at all at that point. Where should I be dismissing the alert view, I mean I don't know when the thread has ended ?

Comment: If your targeted IOS version allows it, the simplest way is probably to use GCD instead of manual threads, that will allow you to _easily_ specify a callback to be executed in the main thread when the background thread is done. Check the example at this page to see it done; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch

Comment: Need to support older iOS versions

Comment: Anyone got any further advice :(

Comment: @Jules When your thread is done, use performSelectorOnMainThread to have it dismiss the alertProgress in the main thread. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

Answer (score 15):

I too faced this issue while i was calling a method by

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:.01];
```

Now it has solved by performing it on main thread

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: This is awesome. Was researching this forever. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

if you are going to do any UI operation it has to be done on main thread..

simply paste the coding inside the following syntax

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

//Your code goes here

});
```

or you can call your method using the following syntax

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourmethod:)withObject:obj waitUntilDone:YES]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

//The easiest way is to call the function using main thread for that.

`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [self doSomething];
});`

Answer (score 3):

Durai answer in Swift 3:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  //Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and used

```
performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
```

to solve it.  Hope that helps.