# How can i call a lot of methods in A thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have a connect method. I want to use it in a thread because it takes long time. But this method triggers other many methods so i get a error message like above.

***_WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x94316f0: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.***

my code is:

```
    __weak LoginViewController *weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_queue_t connectionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("connection Queue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(connectionQueue, ^{
        [weakSelf connect];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [spinner stopAnimating];
        });
    });
```

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679754/tried-to-obtain-the-web-lock-from-a-thread-other-than-the-main-thread-or-the-web

Answer (score 1):

UIKit components like `UIAlertView`, `UIActivityIndicator` cannot be used in threads other than the mainthread. If you want to show alert/activity then you have to show/dismiss or start/stop in main thread only.

I think you are calling `[spinner stopAnimating];` in a thread that is not the main thread. If so then do this in main thread.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stopAnimation) onThread:[NSThread mainThread] withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Comment: No problem about spinner. When i comment out `[weakSelf connect];` i don't take error message.

Comment: `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{` means main thread.

Comment: Then move your [weakSelf connect]; into dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ and check if it is working.

Comment: it is working in main_queue. But i want to working in background not main thread.