# Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, uikit, webserver

I am making an iPhone app that needs to communicate with a server (S3). However, when I execute this code:

```
- (void)submit
{
    dispatch_queue_t Q = dispatch_queue_create("Formula Submit", NULL);
    dispatch_async(Q, ^{
        NSMutableArray *formulas = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://urlremoved.com"]] mutableCopy];

        if (!formulas)
        {
            formulas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }

       [_data addEntriesFromDictionary:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:self.explanationTextView.text, @"explanation", nil]];

        [formulas addObject:_data];

        AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"Access Key Removed" withSecretKey:@"Secret Key Removed"];

        S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:@"File Name Removed" inBucket:@"Bucket Name Removed"];
        por.contentType = @"application/octet-stream";

        NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:formulas format:NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:nil];

        por.data = plistData;
        [s3 putObject:por];
    });

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I get this error/warning in the console:

```
void _WebThreadLockFromAnyThread(bool), 0x20150be0: Obtaining the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. UIKit should not be called from a secondary thread.
```

This message does not seem to affect app performance in any way. It successfully uploads to S3, with no apparent problems.

I am wondering, essentially, if there is a way to make this message *go away*.

Comment: visit the following link it will give u idea
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18173159/730807

Comment: No UI ops here, though.

Comment: I think the below coding does UI job                                 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: Yes, but it's outside of the `dispatch_async` block.