# Why does my code crash with some UIWebView exception?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My App got crashed and gives output as follows:

```
Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   WebThreadLock
2   -[UIWebDocumentView(UIWebDocumentViewTextSelecting) selectionBaseWritingDirection]
3   -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder]
4   -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder]
5   -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder]
6   -[UITextField resignFirstResponder]
7   -[UIView(UITextField) endEditing:]
8   -[UIWindowController _prepareKeyboardForTransition:fromView:]
9   -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:]
10  -[UIViewController presentViewController:withTransition:completion:]
11  -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]
12  -[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:]
13  -[studentlogViewController parse]
14  -[NSThread main]
15  __NSThread__main__
16  _pthread_start
17  thread_start
```

can anyone let me know, i got out of my mind,  i dont have any clue what is happening here

Comment: It's clear that you are plying with webview in background thread

Comment: i am not at all using webview in my class i am parsing xml data and displaying on text

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679754/tried-to-obtain-the-web-lock-from-a-thread-other-than-the-main-thread-or-the-web for an answer to a similar question. You may need to use GCD or some other form of callback to avoid calling `UIKit` methods from a background thread

Comment: hi rich: what about this dd_invokeOnMainThread

Comment: I'm guessing this occurred on iOS 6.1 or earlier. During that time, UITextField internally used a webview to process attributed string layout. This is why you may be seeing a UIWebView exception even though you are not using one directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re parsing some data in the background (which is fine) and then you update the UI from the background thread, which is wrong. You have to update the UI from the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [studentLogViewController parse];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // now present the new view controller
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to do any UI operation it has to be done on main thread..

simply paste the coding inside the following syntax

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Your code goes here
});
```

or you can call your method using the following syntax

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(yourmethod:)withObject:obj waitUntilDone:YES]
```