# UIImage animations don't work in a view pushed without animation

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I've got a view controller whose view contains a `UIImageView` that does animation:

```
//AnimationViewController::ViewDidLoad event:
var ctlAnimations = new UIImageView();

ctlAnimations.AnimationImages = list.ToArray();  //<--list contains the UIImages
ctlAnimations.AnimationDuration = 1.0 * list.Count;
ctlAnimations.StartAnimating();

this.Add(ctlAnimations);
```

This works perfectly: when I push `AnimationViewController` onto the navigation stack, it displays and animates the `UIImage`.

But now I need to show `AnimationViewController` with a custom animated transition:

```
var transition = CATransition.CreateAnimation ();
transition.Duration = 0.3f;
transition.TimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction.FromName(CAMediaTimingFunction.EaseInEaseOut);
transition.Type = CATransition.TransitionFade;
this.View.Layer.AddAnimation (transition, "fade");
//viewController is being pushed with animated=false, because we have a custom animation
base.PushViewController (viewController, false);  
this.View.Layer.RemoveAnimation("fade");
```

This **also** works perfectly, in that the new View transitions into place using the specified custom animation.

But when I push `AnimationViewController` onto the stack **using an animated transition**, it displays but **the animation doesn't run**.  Instead, it shows the first frame of the animation (the first image in the list), and doesn't run it.

So, something about the transition is breaking the ability to animate a `UIImage` in the new view controller, but I simply can't figure out what to do about it.

**Update**: I've noticed that if I tap the NavigationController's back button, but then move off of the back button and let go (so I don't actually go back), the animation starts playing!

Comment: - UIImageView animation also starts when you tap on any button in `AnimationViewController`;

Comment: what happened with the bounty? was it not awarded?

Comment: Not yet, because none of the answers got me any closer to a solution.  What do I do in this situation?

Comment: Not sure it's relevant, but one thing I note is that you are calling RemoveAnimation immediately, rather than setting it to be removed when completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never figured out what the problem was here, but it also turned out that there was some sort of memory leak in `UIImage` such that on some phones my code was crashing.

So I rewrote it to do the animation manually.  Now I set a timer and keep a frame index variable, and every time the timer rings I change the image myself.  This amounts to the same thing, and it turns out it fixes this problem.

Answer (score 1):

PushViewController works like this: Over the current view controller the next view controller is placed you can say pushed onto the stack. From Apple docs its clear that either you need to push view controllers either with animation or without.

Work around:

1. Set the frame of the next view controller's view's x position beyond
   the screen's right
2. Suppose width of the screen is 320, then set the x position of next
   view as 320.
3. Add the next view as subview to the existing one.
4. Now do your custom animation.

Another work around:(a bit more overhead though)

- Take a snapshot programmatically of current view.
- Add the snapshot image as the initial view of next view controller.
- Now push view controller without animation. (User will still see the old view)
- In viewDidAppear of new view controller start your custom animation.

[I have to warn you that this method of taking snapshot might give you a small delay in older devices. Newer devices are pretty fast enough you wont see any lag]

Let me know if any issues in case you are implementing any of these solutions.

Comment: The second work around works for sure because as you said in the update animation starts playing when you tap back button. Just give it a try

Comment: I'll give these a try today, but I don't really understand why these would be necessary.  Why doesn't my animated view play in the first place?

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but your second work around sounds awful, he has an actual bug somewhere, *working around* it with faked screenshots sounds like something a Marketing guy would tell a developer to do so they can sell vaporware

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the animating bit in ViewDidAppear rather than ViewDidLoad.  Also, try using breakpoints and NSLogs to follow what happens after the animation, starting with the ViewDidLoad and ViewDidAppear.  Try having the animation repeat forever so you can see if it has ever been animating or not.

Comment: I tried moving it to viewDidAppear and got the same result.  The animation already does repeat forever, so I think it's clear that it never *starts* animating.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very curious what the culprit is here as well. Why is the animation not displaying correctly in some cases?

My theory is that you have placed animation code in viewWillAppear rather than viewDidAppear. Animation code does not run properly when placed in WILL or SHOULD methods.

Can you please post back what caused the issue?

Answer (score 0):

#### Suspicion #1

I am betting that your code is not being called because it is in ViewDidLoad.  I believe you are creating a customized view stack, that means you need to be using the [ChildViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController:) methods from Cocoa.

I am unfamiliar with MonoTouch (I only write pure CocoaTouch), so this might not be 100% correct

I would be consoling out your viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear methods and absolutely make sure they are being called.  It is my suspicion that viewDidLoad IS NOT.  And this is causing viewDidLoad to not be called on the UIImageView.

In your code you probably need the equivalent of (from objective-c):

```
[self addChildViewController:viewController];
// OR?
[base addChildViewController:viewController];
```

This tells the 'parent' viewController that the Child has been made visible, so call the viewDidLoad/Appear and Unload/Disappear methods when appropriate.  This might not exist in MonoTouch, or the Push methods might not be fully implemented, so you might need to do some hacky (**bad**) stuff like manually calling the viewDidLoad method manually.

#### Suspicion #2

It could also be that your 'list' variable (the one holding the images) is nil.  If that happened the animation would not run. OR maybe it has something to do with the duration of your animation, try to set it to whatever would make it repeat forever.  Be sure it isn't running *REAL FAST* somehow and you are just missing it.

**begin philosophical musing**
Either that or start learning actual Cocoa development :) Not meant as a flame, but definitely meant seriously, you are going to run into problems trying to develop applications through translation layers (custom language-bridges meant to get around writing the base language of a framework/application/platform).

Titanium/MonoTouch/PhoneGap will never produce as robust or high-quality applications as real Objective-C.  And besides that, once you learn Cocoa it will change how you write everything else, and I doubt you will want to go back.  As the wonderful website of the same name says, 'Cocoa is my girlfriend'

Comment: suspicion #3: animation code should be called on the main thread to perform

Comment: That is a pretty good suspicion.  However it is unlikely  the view would have shown at all if he were messing with threading.  UI code should only work on the main thread

Comment: I'm not doing anything with threading.  In viewDidLoad I create a UIImageView, add some images to it, and add the UIImageView to the current view.  The list variable is NOT null nor empty.  The animation DOES repeat forever.

Comment: About using Cocoa, one answer is that by using MonoTouch I can port most of my code to Android, rather than starting from scratch with Java.  Another answer is that MonoTouch is a very thin abstraction layer, mirroring the class hierarchy in iOS very closely, and I haven't yet run into a situation where something exposed by iOS wasn't accessible to me.  I'm proficient in C# and I simply can't imagine that ObjectiveC could be as robust, for me anyway, given the syntax and the need to be so careful with memory management.

Comment: Take note, memory management is _easy_ with ARC, there are only a few situations where you need to know anything about it.  Understood on the reasoning behind MonoTouch, just be careful :).  Android is a big octopus with a few hundred different devices to support.  A one size fits all solution doesn't even really work in the Java world, let alone with something thats being used to generate Java AND Objective-C.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank Do you need to call [super viewDidLoad] or super.viewDidLoad() in MonoTouch?  A missing call to that might cause a problem like this in regular Cocoa.

Comment: You do, and I did.  I just didn't show it in the code snippet.  Good thinking though!

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell the something about UI in IOS. In IOS access to the UI Elements is limited to a single thread.

The single thread would always be the mainThread except in the case when you are running an animation.

Hence when u are performing number of animation at the same instance you have to use

1. beginAnimation.
2. setFrame (or) some methods that changes state of UI element.
3. Repeat step2 for all those objects u are scheduling to animate.
4. comitAnimations to perform all animations at once. (using comit animations ensure all the animations are performed on same thread)

So, I guess here is what happening in ur case.

1. Viewcontroller started an animation to push the view controller into stack.
2. Image view started another animation before finishing first animation.

Look at the links to get a clear idea [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679754/tried-to-obtain-the-web-lock-from-a-thread-other-than-the-main-thread-or-the-web) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372661/iphone-obtaining-the-web-lock-from-a-thread).

Well Let's get into the solution

**Add an ivar and retained property named ctlAnimations to your class**

**In ViewDidLoad (or) ViewDidAppear**

> ```
> self.ctlAnimations = new UIImageView();
> ctlAnimations.image=(UIImage*)[list.toArray() objectAtIndex:0];
> this.Add(ctlAnimations);
> [self performSelector:@selector(startAnimatingImage) afterDelay:0.1];
> ```

**Create a private method named startAnimatingImage with below code**

> ```
> self.ctlAnimations.AnimationImages = list.ToArray();
> ctlAnimations.AnimationDuration = 1.0 * list.Count;
> ctlAnimations.StartAnimating();
> ```

On a brief we just shown first image for a moment when the firstanimation is taken place and then we delayed animation start for 1 second so that it performs after first animation and then starts animating the image.

Go ahead and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

There is the concept for the Main thread. So UIAnimation are actually works on Main Thread and at the same time may be this was happen that another task is performing on the same Main Thread.So that was a case like IOS will give preference according to processes id of each process at a time and for the solution you need to make background thread for the same operations.